# What kind of join do I need to use to create one table from many?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables A, B and C. Each table has an ID and a value field.
What kind of join do I use to consolidate these into one table with an ID field and columns value A, value B, value C?

Naturally, I want only 1 record for each ID in the result table. Thanks.

Example:

Table A:

```
1 x
2 y
```

Table B:

```
2 a
3 b
```

Table C:

```
2 m
```

Result I need:

```
1 x - -
2 y a m
3 - b -
```

Comment: somewhat vague to answer ...

Comment: I've just added example to clarify my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Ids are distributed across all the tables, union them together and group/aggregate on that:

```
SELECT Id, MAX(ValueA) AS ValueA, MAX(ValueB) AS ValueB, MAX(ValueC) AS ValueC
FROM (
    SELECT Id, ValueA, NULL AS ValueB, NULL AS ValueC
    FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, NULL AS ValueA, ValueB, NULL AS ValueC
    FROM TableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, NULL AS ValueA, NULL AS ValueB, ValueC
    FROM TableC
)
GROUP BY Id
```

If each Id is unique and exists once within each table:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA, TableB.ValueB, TableC.ValueC
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.Id = TableC.Id
```

If each Id is unique, exists in TableA and is present either once or doesn't exist in the other tables (non-existant values get supplied as `NULL`s):

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA, TableB.ValueB, TableC.ValueC
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableC ON TableA.Id = TableC.Id
```

If each Id exists uniquely in TableA but may exist multiple times in the other tables, use some sort of aggregation, like `MAX` or `SUM`:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, MAX(TableA.ValueA) AS ValueA, SUM(TableB.ValueB) AS ValueB, MIN(TableC.ValueC) AS ValueC
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
INNER JOIN TableC ON TableA.Id = TableC.Id
GROUP BY TableA.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a left join.  I also used a CTE to get all the ids from the various tables:

```
WITH ids as
(
    SELECT id from table1
    UNION
    SELECT id from table2
    UNION
    SELECT id from table3
)

SELECT distinct ids.id, t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1 
FROM ids
LEFT JOIN Table1 as t1
ON ids.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2
ON ids.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN Table3 as t3
ON ids.id = t3.id
```

Comment: This answer won't work if the id he wants to join on exists t2 or t3 but not in t1.

Comment: Just noticed that.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses FULL JOIN to return one row per ID whether or not the ID exists in all of the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE #A
    ( Id INT NOT NULL
    , Value VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE #B
    ( Id INT NOT NULL
    , Value VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE #C
    ( Id INT NOT NULL
    , Value VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #A (Id, Value)
VALUES (1, 'x'), (2, 'y');

INSERT INTO #B (Id, Value)
VALUES (2, 'a'), (3, 'b');

INSERT INTO #C (Id, Value)
VALUES (2, 'm');


SELECT Id = COALESCE(a.Id, b.Id, c.Id)
    , ValueA = a.Value
    , ValueB = b.Value
    , ValueC = c.Value
FROM #A a
FULL JOIN #B b
    ON a.Id = b.Id
FULL JOIN #C c
    ON a.Id = c.Id;
```