# Join tables on multiple conditions where rows may not have all IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to build a query for a report that will return both budget and transaction data for all account types. The problem is that there are some account types present in the budget table that are not in the transaction table and vice versa. Here are the queries with the relevant information that needs to be joined from each table. First, the budget:

```
Select bp.ProjectID, bp.AccountCategoryID, bp. FiscalYearPeriod, bp.Amount AS BudgetAmount
from BudgetsProject bp
where bp.ProjectId = 1063 and bp.FiscalYearPeriod = 201510
```

[image: Returns the budget table]

The relevant data from the transaction table is found using:

```
SELECT f.ProjectKey, f.AccountCategoryKey, f.PostFiscalPeriodKey, sum(f.IncomeAmount) as IncomeAmount, sum(f.ExpenseAmount) as ExpenseAmount, sum(f.TransactionCount) as TransactionCount
FROM ActualCategoryPivotAccountTypeSubAccountFact f
Where f.ProjectKey = 1063 and f.PostFiscalPeriodKey = 201510
Group by f.ProjectKey, f.AccountCategoryKey, f.PostFiscalPeriodKey
```

[image: Returns the transaction table]

The problem is that when I attempt to FULL JOIN the tables not every AccountCategoryKey value is in every row for both tables so I end up missing rows of data. I need to have every possible Accountcategory show in the result set and have NULLs where corresponding transaction or budget isn't available.

I know that this answer exists: [What kind of join do I need to use to create one table from many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626522/what-kind-of-join-do-i-need-to-use-to-create-one-table-from-many)
 but the tables must be joined on matching Project, AccountCategory, and FiscalYear fields and I'm not sure how to apply the solution presented there to a case where I need to be joining on multiple conditions.

EDIT: If this is helpful I've added logic to recreate tables here:

```
Create Table BudgetsReport (
AccountCategoryID int NOT NULL,
ProjectID int NOT NULL,
FiscalYearPeriod char(6) NOT NULL,
Amount numeric(10,2)
);

Create Table ActualCategoryPivotAccountTypeSubAccountFact (
PostFiscalPeriodKey int,
ProjectKey int,
AccountCategoryKey int,
IncomeAmount money,
ExpenseAmount money,
TransactionCount int
);

INSERT INTO BudgetsReport VALUES (1063, 5, 201510, 1626.00), (1063, 15, 201510, 8.00), (1063, 26, 201510, 1757.00), (1063, 36, 201510, 0.00), (1063, 38, 201510, 6508.00), (1063, 41, 201510, 115000.00), (1063, 42, 201510, 667.00), (1063, 43, 201510, 167.00), (1063, 51, 201510, 7289.00), (1063, 54, 201510, 21.00), (1063, 81, 201510, 138164.00), (1063, 87, 201510, 83.00), (1063, 88, 201510, 54.00), (1063, 90, 201510, 833.00);

INSERT INTO ActualCategoryPivotAccountTypeSubAccountFact VALUES (1063, 2, 201510, 0.00, 0.00, 214), (1063, 5, 201510, 0.00, 1004.42, 1), (1063, 15, 201510, 0.00, 3.92, 1), (1063, 26, 201510, 0.00, 1556.44, 10), (1063, 34, 201510, 0.00, 26.37, 1), (1063, 36, 201510, 0.00, 0.00, 19), (1063, 38, 201510, 0.00, 5764.65, 10), (1063, 41, 201510, 0.00, 131857.10, 29), (1063, 51, 201510, 0.00, 6456.27, 10), (1063, 54, 201510, 0.00, .44, 1), (1063, 87, 201510, 0.00, 28.30, 1), (1063, 90, 201510, 0.00, 545.96, 120), (1063, 93, 201510, 149945.01, 0.00, 213);
```

Comment: Can you post the query that you've tried so far?

Comment: SELECT 
  f.ProjectKey, f.AccountCategoryKey, f.PostFiscalPeriodKey, sum(f.IncomeAmount) as IncomeAmount, sum(f.ExpenseAmount) as ExpenseAmount, sum(f.TransactionCount) as TransactionCount, bp.Amount as BudgetAmount
 FROM
  ActualCategoryPivotAccountTypeSubAccountFact f  
  FULL JOIN BudgetsProject bp ON f.PostFiscalPeriodKey = bp.FiscalYearPeriod and bp.ProjectId = f.ProjectKey and bp.AccountCategoryId = f.AccountCategoryKey 
 WHERE f.PostFiscalPeriodKey = 201510 and f.ProjectKey = 1063 
 Group By f.ProjectKey, f.AccountCategoryKey, f.PostFiscalPeriodKey, bp.Amount

Comment: Above query gives every accountcategorykey included in the transaction table but excludes ones from the budget table that are not present in the transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

Having those predicates in your where clause (`WHERE f.PostFiscalPeriodKey = 201510 and f.ProjectKey = 1063`) are what's killing you, I think.  You could move them to the on clause, but with a full join I don't know what that might end up with.  Maybe try using a derived table with your constraints, and then join to that.

```
select
...
FROM
(
select * 
from
ActualCategoryPivotAccountTypeSubAccountFact
where
PostFiscalPeriodKey = 201510
and ProjectKey = 1063) F
full join  BudgetsProject bp
on f.PostFiscalPeriodKey = bp.FiscalYearPeriod 
and bp.ProjectId = f.ProjectKey 
and bp.AccountCategoryId = f.AccountCategoryKey
```

You could also try building a driver table with all the possible keys, and then outer joining to it.  Not sure how this would perform though.

Comment: From what I can tell adding the conditions to the ON clause instead of where returns a lot of extraneous data from FULL JOINing to the budget table. It basically returns the entire budget table for budget amount, even values outside the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a CTE and storing the possible account types and periods.  Then left join to the actuals and budgets.

Another option would be to create a temp table with those values first then perform the select operation.